# what wrong with this function to add element to a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is my code :

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

void add(Node *head, Node *node) {
    Node *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    if(head==NULL) {
        head=node;
    }
    else {
        while(ptr->next != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = node;
    }
}

Node* create(int a) {
    Node *node;
    node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->data = a;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

int main() {
    Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Node *node;
        node = create(i);
        add(head, node);
    }
}
```

Problem is : head is getting redefined in the function add, everytime add is called. why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `add` is receiving a **copy** of your pointer when you call it.  You set `head` in that function, but that changes the local copy, not other variable named `head` in `main()`.  You would need to do something like this (I just put the lines to change; the rest look okay):

```
  void add(Node **head, Node *node) {
    *head = node;
  }



int main() {
    add(&head, node);
 }
```

Comment: Can I avoid using `**` in some other way of implementing linkedlist ?

Comment: I guess I can avoid using `**` but not directly assigning to `head` but instead use pointers relative to head.

Comment: @YugalJindle: In C, I'm not sure how to avoid passing in a pointer to your `head` pointer elegantly.  In C++ you could use a reference.  In C, the only other thing I can think of is to have your `add` function return the new head, then calls look like `head = add(head, node);`.  But, that's probably worse.